# Unable to find docker image locally despite docker pull

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to run the following docker image in Windows 10: https://hub.docker.com/r/trzeci/emscripten/

When pulling the image using `docker pull trzeci/emscripten`, running `docker image ls` yields

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
trzeci/emscripten   latest              e4ef88217e2e        3 months ago        932MB
```

However, running the command

```
docker run --rm -v `pwd`:`pwd` trzeci/emscripten emcc helloworld.cpp -o helloworld.js -e

>PS C:\Windows\system32> docker run --rm -v \`pwd\`:\`pwd\` trzeci/emscripten emcc helloworld.cpp -o helloworld.js -e        Unable to find image 'emcc:latest' locally

>C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for emcc, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
```

See `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe run --help`.

Why isn't it found? Do I have to build it as well?

Comment: Are you trying to mount a directory called pwd into a directory called pwd in the container? Or is it supposed to the working directory locally, and a specific directory in the container?

Comment: @MikeHawkins My goal was the latter

Comment: What does the `pwd` command on its own output?  The important thing from that error message is that `docker` is interpreting the `emcc` argument as the image name, not `trzeci/emscripten`.  Another useful trick is just to put `echo` at the front of the line to see how the shell expands it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're receiving that error is because the run command doesn't register your volume definition. Volumes cannot be specified with grave accent (`). They must be the exact names of the directories that you wish to map.

Because of the incorrect naming of the intended directory mappings, the command skips your volume definition, and assumes that emcc is your image. Try this:

```
docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:/src trzeci/emscripten emcc helloworld.cpp -o helloworld.js -e
```

`${PWD}` prints the working directory in PowerShell. If you're using cmd, then replace `${PWD}` with `%cd%`. The reason i put `/src` as the target , is because it is the working directory of the image.